# what are the conditions under which libcurl will exhibit - RST after receiving SYN from server and libcurl error 7

Tags: libcurl

Under which condition is libcurl likely to throw RST after receiving SYN from server, I get CURL error code 7.

I have used the same piece of code in two different DC (data center), when it is local DC request is serviced, but remote DC response is curl error 7.

Initially I thought it was connect timeout, but that would be CURL error code 28.

tcpdump shows
    client -> server - SYN
    server -> client - SYN
    client -> server - RST

any suggestions?

i suspected it was out of socket issue but that can't be because SYN already created port

Answer (score 0):

after changing the 
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, timeout);

the requests are going through.

It seems like my assumption that connect timeout should always result in 28 is incorrect. especially in the case then TCP handshake isn't completed